# How can I decode php code that using goto statement?

Tags: php, decode

I have several large files as below:

```
public function index()
{
    goto E9e2246508a1d047;
    b59f99a7185ea4f4:
    return View("\x65\155\160\154\x6f\171\x65\162\56\x74\x72\x61\156\163\141\x63\x74\x69\x6f\156\x73", ["\x70\x61\147\x65" => $F44ac1942f77c961]);
    goto b4ef380f386bfff0;
    E021694d1d524d6a:
    $F44ac1942f77c961 = $C52f2627c8748472->lastpage();
    goto b59f99a7185ea4f4;
    E9e2246508a1d047:
    $C52f2627c8748472 = UserTransaction::where("\165\x73\145\162\x5f\x69\x64", Auth::id())->orderBy("\143\x72\x65\141\164\x65\x64\x5f\141\x74", "\x61\163\x63")->paginate(10);
    goto E021694d1d524d6a;
    b4ef380f386bfff0:
}
```

From [UnPHP - The Online PHP Decoder](https://www.unphp.net/)  I decode it to :

```
public function index()
{
    goto E9e2246508a1d047;
    b59f99a7185ea4f4:
    return View("employer.transactions", ["page" => $F44ac1942f77c961]);
    goto b4ef380f386bfff0;
    E021694d1d524d6a:
    $F44ac1942f77c961 = $C52f2627c8748472->lastpage();
    goto b59f99a7185ea4f4;
    E9e2246508a1d047:
    $C52f2627c8748472 = UserTransaction::where("user_id", Auth::id())->orderBy("created_at", "asc")->paginate(10);
    goto E021694d1d524d6a;
    b4ef380f386bfff0:
}
```

The name of the variables is not very important to me (Though it's better to be true).

But I want to delete `goto` command and have a clean code.

Comment: Where did this come from, is this supposed to be some kind of obfuscation? // You are going to need some sort of parser, that takes this apart into individual statements, and then “follows” those GOTOs to determine in which order the rest of the statements will actually execute.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the code with gotos:

```
public function index()
{
    goto E9e2246508a1d047;
    E9e2246508a1d047:
    $C52f2627c8748472 = UserTransaction::where("user_id", Auth::id())->orderBy("created_at", "asc")->paginate(10);
    goto E021694d1d524d6a;
    E021694d1d524d6a:
    $F44ac1942f77c961 = $C52f2627c8748472->lastpage();
    goto b59f99a7185ea4f4;
    b59f99a7185ea4f4:
    return View("employer.transactions", ["page" => $F44ac1942f77c961]);
    goto b4ef380f386bfff0;
    b4ef380f386bfff0:
}
```

Then delete them:

```
public function index()
{
    $C52f2627c8748472 = UserTransaction::where("user_id", Auth::id())->orderBy("created_at", "asc")->paginate(10);
    $F44ac1942f77c961 = $C52f2627c8748472->lastpage();
    return View("employer.transactions", ["page" => $F44ac1942f77c961]);
}
```

Comment: How can I do this? My files are large. This was an small example. Is there a website or program that does it automatically?

Comment: I did it by hand, reordering one after the other. I suppose there is a way of doing this with an automated (python for instance) script, as each goto section is always 3 lines long.

Comment: I definitely need an online tool or software to do this. The codes are very wide and complex - [How can I replace and remove all goto statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780441/how-can-i-replace-and-remove-all-goto-statements) - Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution after passing the code through the parser from your provided url:

```
$result = $source; // source code
$goto = []; // collect all goto blocks to remove them after

$result = preg_replace_callback('/goto (\w+);*/', function($m) use ($source, &$goto) {
    $goto[] = $m[1].':';
    preg_match("/{$m[1]} *:(((?!goto).)*)/s", $source, $m);
    return $m[1];
}, $source);

$result = str_replace($goto, '', $result); // replace goto:

$result = preg_replace('/([\r\n])+\s+/', "\n", $result);

// view the result
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities($result);
echo '</pre>';die();
```

Comment: you need to adjust a bit the code, but this is not impossible